# Android VM - Connection Error

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin, hyper-v

Caros, bom dia!

Eu não estou conseguindo conexão no meu emulador do android, alguém poderia me ajudar? Eu estou usando o VisualStudio Emulator for Android.

O meu projeto está compilando, e executando certinho, mas não consigo conexão, preciso configurar alguma coisa no Hyper-V ?

O erro acontece, quando tento conectar em algum web service, por isso eu imagino que seja problema de conexão do dispositivo.

Segue abaixo código C#:

`public static async Task<List<Model.Livros>> GetAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://mvalivros.azurewebsites.net/api/livros");
                var livros = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Livros>>(json);
                return livros;
            }
        }`

Erro no emulador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configurações da VM:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Att.
Felipe

---

Tiago S, preciso alterar o gateway tambem? Fiz o que você falou, e continuo sem conexão, da uma olhada abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Valeu cara!

Att.
Felipe

Comment: Consegue acessar qualquer outro site através do navegador do emulador android?

Comment: Então cara, não. Esse erro que está gerando é quando eu tento acessar algum site no navegador do emulador.

Comment: Tenta ver se o Firewall não esta bloqueando, desative e teste.

Comment: Desativei o firewall aqui, e nada tambem. Cara, eu preciso deixar habilitado somente um dos adaptadores? Tipo, deixar somente o interno, ou o externo? E se deixar somente o interno, eu preciso compartilhar minha rede?

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive o mesmo problema.

A solução para mim foi ir nas configurações do `wifi` do `android` e configurar manualmente a rede, alterando o `IP settings` como `Static` e o endereço de IP sendo o do minha maquina porém acrescentando 1 no final. ex:

> **Minha maquina**:192.168.0.5;
>
> **Android**: 192.168.0.51;

Comment: Você configurou manualmente a rede wifi? Se for isso, pra mim não adianta, não tenho wifi aqui, preciso configurar a rede local. Caso eu tenha entendido errado, desconsidere haha

Comment: Rede wifi do emulador,dentro dele...

Comment: A sim! Então, aqui não daria certo. Preciso configurar a rede local..

Comment: Não entendi o seu problema agora...rsrs   mas segue o caminho para você acessar as configurações do wifi Settings>Wifi>Modify network. Eu estou utilizando o emulador com o lollipop e para aparecer a opção de modify network eu preciso manter apertado

Comment: Esse caminho eu sei. O problema aqui, é que não tenho WiFi, eu preciso que a rede local, seja compartilhada com a da minha máquina virtual. Eu estou conectado em rede cabeada, não em WiFi, por isso que falei que não daria certo haha

Comment: Eu entendi, você não precisa ter o wifi na sua maquina local. Você precisa fazer as alterações na maquina virtual (Emulador), lá tem o wifi. Aqui eu não precisei fazer nada na maquina local

Comment: Isso me ajudou.

Comment: Ata! Entendi Tiago! Cara, vou tentar aqui, depois do almoço ja respondo pra você, valeu pela dica!